# Substituting classes that adopt a particular protocol (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, ios, protocols

In Objective-c if two classes adopt a particular protocol can instances of the classes be used interchangeably?

Say I have the following code:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@required
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeObject *object;
@end

@interface ClassA <MyProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeObject *object;
// ...
@end

@interface ClassB <MyProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeObject *object;
// ...
@end
```

Can I substitute `(id <MyProtocol>)instanceOfClassB` when a method expects an instance of `ClassA` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Instances of different classes that conform to the same protocol can be used interchangeably when the API is explicitly typed that way though, e.g.:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id <MyProtocol>)someObj;
```